# BroadcastReceiver for Mobile Data - Listening for On/Off State

Tags: android, mobile, broadcastreceiver

Is there a way to listen for Mobile Data state in Android?

I don't mean Mobile **Connectivity**. I mean Mobile **State**.

In my Manifest xml file, I already have these:

```
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE" />
```

I can listen to almost all Mobile STATE changes.

When WiFi and Mobile are active and I shut down Mobile, my App doesn't see this change of state because there's no connectivity change (WiFi is connected to the Internet) and ANY_DATA_STATE is not fired.

Is there exist a way to get this event in Android?

Thank you!

Comment: No way?
No way to listen to global setting changes?

Comment: It seems there's no way to listen to the mobile data setting in Android.